# Creating a custom Ubuntu core image for Intel Joule

Tags: kernel, compiling, ubuntu-core, snap

I am a newbie to the Linux kernel compilation and I am trying to create an Ubuntu core image. Although there is an image for Intel Joule I want to compile one of my own as I ll patch some changes later on in my project so it is good to know how to build using snapcraft.

I have followed the steps according to the "Board enablement overview" page from Ubuntu core.

Compiled the kernel snap (I took one of the reference kernel snaps available [here](https://github.com/snapcore/sample-kernels/tree/master)), and the gadget snap from [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~snappy-dev/snappy-hub/snappy-systems/files/106?start_revid=106).

Created the Json file and created the image as per the link but when I flashed it on a sd card and tried to boot. It hangs after I select Ubuntu core from the Grub menu. Am I missing any key things to be done or configured. The kernel from Git hub is supposed to be configured for x86_64 architecture.

Comment: There are gadget and kernel for Intel Joule in the store. The name of gadget is **joule** as well as the kernel is **joule-linux**. You can use these two snaps in your model assertion and built your own image.

Answer (score 1):

i'd suggest to try each snap on its own ...

i.e. build the gadget, build an image with the official pc kernel, see if that boots ...

https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/guides/build-device/image-building

only then start playing with your own kernel ...

also, the new location for the official amd64 gadget is at:

https://github.com/snapcore/pc-amd64-gadget

Comment: Thanks for that info. I tried as you mentioned. Built the gadget snap and took the official kernel but I ended up with this message from Grub 
error: not a regular file.
error: no server is specified.
alloc magic is broken at 0x6b38ab00: 6b2d6420
Aborted. Press any key to exit.

Later I tried to get official pc gadget and pc kernel so I just wrote the Json file, signed the assertion and built the image. The result was still the same.
Is there an official Joule gadget or the Joule-Linux kernel available somewhere on Github or Intel support page ? That would make life lot easier..